# UFW allow all IP from ASN

Tags: server, iptables, firewall, ufw

How to allow access to ubuntu with UFW firewall for all addresses belonging to one ICT provider with its ASN number (Is it possible?)?

Comment: No, not directly. Firewalls generally operate on IP adresses, not ASN's. You could periodically fetch IP's belonging to som ASN, but it would not be UFW; it would be custom software.